# how to use built in functions for excel in office app development

Tags: excel, office-addins, office-app

I am trying to develop `office app` for Excel for that i want to use the built in functions of excel like `abs`,`sum`,`Avg` and so on.

I have gone through the `office app documentation` but didn't found any solution

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj220082.aspx

Can any one suggest what is the best way to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to find what you need in the VBA functions.  A good list of them is [here.](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_vba.php)  Just prepend the functions with vba. when using them.  For example:

```
Dim LResult As String

LResult = VBA.Left("Alphabet",3)
```

Comment: Is VBA and Dim are Javascript/office app functions? No i think, so how can i use them in my javascript files.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Hmmm, [mootools](http://mootools.net/) js library has plenty of functions.